# redirecting with mod_rewrite based on http referer

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://www.google.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.google.com/ [L,R]
```

What I'm trying to do with this .htaccess file is, for test purposes, to redirect all http requests coming  from google.com (be it http or https) to google.com. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a `!` before the `^` which means to negate, so it was looking for a `%{HTTP_REFERER}` that did not start with `https://www.google.com` or `http://www.google.com`

When from what you have mentioned you wanted to the opposite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www.google.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com/ [L,R]
```